# Designing a database schema for cities that works for cities throughout the world

Tags: database, database-design

In the United States every deliverable mail address (that I know of anyway) has a postal code. For a schema that works for the United States, I have come up with the following tables:

## country

country_id (PK)
iso3166_1_alpha2
iso3166_1_alpha3
name  (NN,UQ)

## metro

metro_id (PK)
name (NN,UQ)

## city

city_id  (PK)
country_id (FK,NN)
metro_id (FK)
name (NN)
lng
lat

## postal

postal_id (PK)
country_id (FK, NN)
name (NN, UQ)
lng
lat

## city_postal

city_id (FK)
postal_id (FK)

The logic here is as follows:

1. Every city belongs to a country (e.g., Portland -> United States).
2. Some countries have regions (e.g., Alaska, United States), but not
   all do.
3. Regions do not matter because postal codes are unique
   identifiers (e.g., Only one Portland is identified by 97267 postal
   code).
4. Countries without postal codes (e.g., Ireland), have unique
   city names (my assumption: there does not exist two Galways in Ireland).

What I want to be sure of is that this structure works for cities throughout the world. Is my assumption wrong that the only thing that matters are cities and countries? Should I be using regions? For example, are there areas that do not use postal codes, and have duplicate city names because the cities are in different regions?

**EDIT**

Just in case it matters, I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 with PostGIS extension. Also, there is a UNIQUE constraint on city table, columns country_id and name (same goes for postal table). So, there is only one Portland in the United States; however, that is fine because for the United States I will be using postal codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailing addresses throughout the world are FUBAR.

Ireland doesn't use postal codes (outside of Dublin).

The United Kingdom is a country that contains other countries (and a province).

Some cities contain postal codes, some postal codes contain cities.

Some zips cross state boundaries.

Postal codes are not unique across countries ("50170" appears in 10 countries).

Sometimes a mailing address is not in a town or city (just a "surveyed area")

I would read Hay's Enterprise Model Patterns chapter 12 on int'l addresses.

You could try something like this:

```
MAILING_ADDRESS
id
postal_code null FK POSTAL_CODES
surveyed_area FK GEO_AREA (must be a city or surveyed area)
suite null

GEO_AREA
id
name

COUNTRY : GEO_AREA

PRIMARY_DIVISION (STATE/PROV/UK COUNTRY) : GEO AREA
country_id FK GEO_AREA (must be a country)

CITY : GEO_AREA
primary_division_id FK GEO_AREA (must be a primary division)

SURVEYED_AREA : GEO_AREA
parent_id FK GEO_AREA (must be a primary division or city)
```

Comment: I'm currently reading the chapter you suggested in Enterprise Model Patterns, and it's pretty obvious the problem is far more complex than my database schema allows for. The UML diagram in Figure 12-5 is going to be very helpful. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!