# Best way to store users address into european database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I would like to storing user's address (country-region-town) into a database. This database is the core of a european app. I have a table of countries and foreach country, I have two tables, one for regions and one for towns/cities. 
So, what's the best way to storing user's address into database?

I could create different tables foreach country and rename them "users_italian", "users_french" with columns "idUsers" and "idTown" and I should connect them with the respective town table. It's simple but this mode does not convince me because there would be too many tables.

alternatively I could create a table "users_country" with "idUsers" and "idCountry" (foreign key) and I should memorize region and country into another table "users_address" with "idUsers", "region" and "town", but with string date type, example:

**users**(idUsers:1, email:useremail@mail.com, psw:secrethashedpsw, token:secrettoken)

**country** (idCountry:1, Country: "United Kingdom")

**users_country** (idUsers:1, idCountry:1(refer to United Kingdom))

**users_address** (idUsers:1, region:"England", town:"London", zip: SW1H 0TL (example))

Also this mode does not convince me because the database would not be normalized, but it's simple to realize it! and the query select it's simple too. I could create different tables about "users_region", "users_town" and "users_zip", but the storing with strings does not convince me.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Designing a database schema for cities that works for cities throughout the world](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859736/designing-a-database-schema-for-cities-that-works-for-cities-throughout-the-worl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One table per country?  NO!

Have a single `users` table.  It would have

Plan A:  address and either city+region+country.

Plan B:  address plus id linking to (normalized) table of cities.  `Cities` contains city+region+country.

Normalizing country, for example, adds complexity without adding any benefit.

Comment: I thought, If I use 4 tables? country - regions - provinces - cities? I would use FK to concatenate them and an unique table for users, users_cities

Comment: Textbooks say "normalize".  Reality says "don't over-normalize".  Try it both ways; use it as a learning experience.